# fnpct autocite causes whitespace problems with csquotes blockcquote

Tags: biblatex, csquotes, fnpct

In the following example, using `fnpct` for the biblatex `autocite` command causes unwanted whitespace when a period occurs directly after the the quote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{greenwade93,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
    }
    @book{goossens93,
        author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
        title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
        year      = "1993",
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid,date=year,autocite=footnote,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite} % used by csquotes

\usepackage{fnpct}
\AdaptNoteOpt\autocite\multfootcite

\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
    \null
    \vfill
    \blockcquote[see][123]{greenwade93}{Famous quote}. But the period causes an unwanted space to appear.
    \blockcquote[see][123]{greenwade93}{Which is fixed by moving the period inside the quotation.} See?

    The problem is caused by \texttt{fnpct}.

    \texttt{fnpct} is needed to quote multiple authors at once, but in separate footnotes\autocite{greenwade93}\autocite{goossens93}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is it possible to configure `fnpct` to not add space between quotation mark and period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see the issue here is that handing control of `\autocite` over to `fnpct` destroys `\autocite`'s ability to remove preceding whitespace. With `biblatex`'s definition

```
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}.
```

and

```
Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}.
```

produce the same output since `\autocite` issues `\unspace`. But as soon as `fnpct` takes the reins, those two lines behave differently.

Usually this is not going to be much of a problem since you probably never leave a space before `\footnote` or `\autocite` anyway. But with the default settings of `csquotes` commands like `\blockcquote` leave a space before they call `\autocite` (assuming the usual definition of `biblatex`'s citation commands that make sense: many commands need a space in front of the `\...cite` so they don't stick to the text before and `\footcite`, `\autocite` and friends can deal with preceding space just fine). You can explicitly tell `csquotes` not to leave a space before calling the citation command by redefining `\mkccitation`, cf. also page 30 of the [`csquotes` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csquotes/csquotes.pdf),

```
\renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{#1}
```

The full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid,date=year,autocite=footnote,giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\renewcommand{\mkccitation}[1]{#1}

\usepackage{fnpct}
\AdaptNoteOpt\autocite\multfootcite

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
    \null
    \vfill
    \blockcquote[see][123]{sigfridsson}{Famous quote}. But the period causes an unwanted space to appear.
    \blockcquote[see][123]{sigfridsson}{Which is fixed by moving the period inside the quotation.} See?

    The problem is caused by \texttt{fnpct}.

    \texttt{fnpct} is needed to quote multiple authors at once, but in separate footnotes\autocite{sigfridsson}\autocite{sigfridsson}

  Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}.

  Lorem\autocite{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

then gives the expected output.

[image: Output of the example. The <code>fnpct</code>-controlled footnotes don't suppress previous space. <code>\blockcquote</code> displays as intended again.]

<sub><strike>I'm still having trouble uploading output pictures. Sorry. If you would like to add images of the result, feel free to do so.</strike> See https://v1.overleaf.com/read/hgvsffpjwjbt for a demo.</sub>

Comment: Thank you @moewe for clarifying what's happening here

Comment: I added an equivalent to `\unspace` to the next release of `fnpct`.